# how to program using registers on raspberrypi with C language?

Tags: pi-2

I want to use registers when programming on the Raspberry Pi using the C language. Is it possible?

Comment: What registers are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about running Linux. Yes it is, by mapping the physical addresses to virtual (userspace) memory.

The broadcom [datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZv8aHjNbNAhXECpoKHXEQAukQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.adafruit.com%2Fimages%2Fproduct-files%2F2885%2FBCM2835Datasheet.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG-7LF2yXeuU3kuUtkx3S0cfFQ6aw&sig2=O94_ZlLVegI2vfnPYDeBoQ) will be your best friend while looking at [this](http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/15).

Once you understood how it is done you should take this [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/50513/33564) of mine into account.